# Extensions of Function Fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Suppose $f,g\in k[X,Y]$ where $k$ is algebraically closed and $f,g$ irreducible. Suppose we have an injective map $$\phi: C_g\to C_f$$
where $$C_g = k[X,Y]/(f) \text{ and }C_f = k[X,Y]/(g)$$ and where $\phi$ is morphisms of $k$-algebras.

Such a morphism induces, which we will denote by the same notation, $\phi: K_g\to K_f$, a morphism of $k$-algebras between the field of fractions.

The goal here is to show that $K_f$ is a finite field extension of $K_g$ by using an "elementary" argument. For instance, how does one use the resultant of two polynomials to get an algebraic relation for $(X\bmod f)$ and $(Y\bmod f)$.

I considered the special case where $g=Y$ and $f = Y^n - p(X)$ with $\phi$ is the "inclusion" map. Here clearly $K_f$ is a finite extension of degree $n$, but the Resultant is either 0 or does not lead to anything interesting.

Comment: For any $a\in \phi(Frac(C_g))-K$, $K(X)[a]$ is a finite dimensional $K(X)$ vector space, this gives a non-zero polynomial such that $P(X,a)=0$ which implies that $K(a)[X]$ is a finite dimensional $K(a)$ vector space, whence $Frac(C_f)$ is a finite dimensional $Frac(C_g)$ vector space.

Comment: Bourbaki would have called your $C_g$, $C_f$ and vice versa.

Comment: @reuns Unfortunately, your comment is not clear to me. Can you provide more details? What is $K$ here? And what is $X$ here, is the original indeterminate or the mod class of it?

Comment: $X$ is the element of $C_f$, which is also transcendental over $K$.

Comment: @reuns Why is $K(X)[a]$ fin. dim. / $K(X)$? Presumably because $a$ is algebraic over $K(X)$. But why? We know that $f(X,Y) = 0$ and that $a = a(X,Y)$. If we can solve for $Y$ and write $Y = b(X,a)$ as a polynomial in terms of $X$ and $a$ then we get relation $f(X, b(X,a)) = 0$, which shows that $a$ is algebraic over $K(X)$. So how do you conclude that $a$ is algebraic over $K(X)$?

Comment: $K(X)[Y]$ is a finite dimensional $K(X)$-vector space because $f$ depends on $Y$, and $K(X)[a]$ is a sub-vector space.

Comment: @reuns Thank you, it now makes sense. That is a very nice argument, and surprisingly looks so trivial but it is not easy to find.